# how to customize sort functionality in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add sort functionality to the table headers which contains different data types in each column so I did something like this:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th ng-click="sortItems('stringCol')">Name</th>
    <th ng-click="sortItems('dateCol')">Date Col</th>
    <th ng-click="sortItems('numCol')">Number Col</th>
    <th ng-click="sortItems('currencyCol')">Currency Col</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
        <td>{{item.stringCol}}</td>
        <td>{{item.dateCol}}</td>
        <td>{{item.numCol}}</td>
        <td>{{item.currencyCol}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

here is the js :

```
$scope.sortColumn = "stringCol";
    $scope.reverseSort = false;

    $scope.sortData = function(column){
        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;
    };
```

it treats all data as string so not working properly for non-string columns. In addition each column can have null values too. 
I am really new in angular js and I know I need propbably a custom filter function but I don't know how to do it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could implement your own comparator, providing any sort functionality you desire. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: @ste2425 thanks for providing that. But it doesn't say the custom comparator should be a custom filter or I can attach it as a function to the scope object. Do you know any example that I can take a look at it?

Comment: the last example of the docs show you how to use a custom comparator, its just like a normal array sort comparator, you receive two elements and return `-1, 0, 1` to indicate the relative position between the two elements.

Comment: Thanks @ste2425 that was really helpful.

Comment: No problem, if you find a solution consider answering it yourself which may help others who come across your question.